# class-validator doesn't validate entity

Tags: node.js, typescript, postgresql, nestjs, typeorm

Can I use `class-validator` to validate `Entity` columns?

This doesn't validate the columns:

```
import { IsEmail } from 'class-validator';

@Entity()
export class Admin extends BaseEntity {

  @Column({ unique: true })
  @IsEmail()
  email: string;

}
```

However when I use the `class-validator` anywhere else in the code other than entities it validates properly and doesn't allow for bad inputs.

This works:

```
@InputType()
export class RegisterInput {

  @Field()
  @IsEmail()
  email: string;

}
```

Comment: Do you use the `Admin` class an an input DTO type?

Comment: I'd say that is better to no expose your entites and instead rely only in DTO => Entity mapping

Comment: No I use `RegisterInput` as dto

Comment: This shouldn't be done on a Database level. A DTO with a Validation pipe will be the best solution for this. You check the incoming request and then let it communicate with your service which interacts with the database.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Entity should be clean

```
@Entity()
    export class Admin extends BaseEntity {
    
      @Column({ unique: true })
      email: string;
    
    }
```

While you define a DTO for checking the incoming request.

```
export class AdminDto {

@IsEmail() 
email: string;

}
```

In your controller, you would check the incoming request with your AdminDto.

```
@Controlller('route')
export class AdminController {
constructor(private yourService: yourserviceClass)

@Post('/api')
async createSomething(@Body('email', ValidationPipe) email: string){ //Your request body //would be checked against your DTO
this.yourService.createMethod(email)
}
```

Hope this answers your question.

Comment: I had  a same issue. This is what i was looking for . Thank You